# "error:no matching function call to ..."

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am having this error. " **error:no matching function to call 'Employee::Employee()'** ". When i write a constructor about "faculty class" i am having this error.
Can you help me with this issue? I am begging for help :( .
There is 2 more classes. "Date" and "Person". "Person" is the super class of "Employee".

---

Employee.h

```
 #ifndef GK_EMPLOYEE_H
 #define GK_EMPLOYEE_H
 #include "GK_Person.h"

 class Employee:public Person
{
public:

Employee(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob, Date* dob,Date* start,char* title,int salary,bool fulltime =true);// start refers to dynamic memory
//virtual ~Employee();
void SetTitle(char* title);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const Employee&);

friend class Faculty;
private:
char* m_title;
int m_salary;
bool m_fulltime;
Date* m_start;// date started working
};


#endif // GK_EMPLOYEE_H
```

---

Employee.cpp

```
#include "GK_Employee.h"

Employee::Employee(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob, Date* dob,Date* start,char* title,int salary,bool fulltime/*=true*/){

m_name=name;
m_surname=surname;
m_sex=sex;
m_pob=pob;
m_dob=dob;
m_start=start;
m_title=title;
m_salary=salary;
m_fulltime=fulltime;

}

void Employee::SetTitle(char* title){
m_title = title;
}
```

---

Faculty.h

```
  #ifndef GK_FACULTY_H
  #define GK_FACULTY_H
  #include "GK_Employee.h"

 class Faculty :public Employee
{
public:
Faculty(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob, Date* dob,Date* start,int level,int salary,Date* dolat,bool fulltime = true);
//virtual ~Faculty();
char GetType() const{return'F';}
void Promote(Date* dt);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,const Faculty&);

 private:
 Date* m_dolat;// date of last academic title owned
int m_level;// 0 for Dr., 1 for Ass.Prof.Dr., 2 for Assoc.Prof.Dr. and 3 for Prof.Dr.
};


 #endif // GK_FACULTY_H
```

---

Faculty.cpp

```
#include "GK_Faculty.h"

Faculty::Faculty(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob, Date* dob,Date* start,int level,int salary,Date* dolat,bool fulltime/*= true*/){

}
```

Comment: Why are you using char pointers?  Why not use std::string?  Same thing with your Date.  Why a pointer to a Date?

Comment: Some of the parts of code has written by my teacher. And i am not allowed to change it.I know it is dumb but what can i do ?

Comment: Honestly, it is a terrible design and shouldn't even have been considered by any teacher. If one of those char pointers you're assigning to your Employee object goes out of scope, your Employee object is now invalid. So how are you to acutally *use* this class, given these restrictions?  Sure, you can write a class that happens to compile, but when you now need to write a program that uses it, you will be back to SO with another question as to why your program crashes or doesn't work properly -- trust me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Faculty` derives from `Employee`, you need to initalize the members of `Employee` in your `Faculty` constructor. This must be done by calling the constructor of `Employee`. If `Employee` had a default constructor (i.e. one without any parameters), then the compiler would do this implicitly for you. But `Employee` only defines the following constructor:

```
Employee(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob, Date* dob,Date* start,char* title,int salary,bool fulltime =true);// start refers to dynamic memory
```

The compiler cannot tell what arguments to pass to this c'tor, so you need to call it yourself from inside the `Faculty` c'tor. Like this:

```
#include "GK_Faculty.h"

Faculty::Faculty(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob, Date* dob,Date* start,int level,int salary,Date* dolat,bool fulltime/*= true*/)
: Employee(name,surname,sex,pob,dob,start,"mytitle",salary,fulltime)
{

}
```

Comment: I did what you recommended. But i got another error. "error:title was not declared in this scope."

Comment: alright, i didn't compile that code. I thought the parameters of `Employee`  c'tor were equal to those of `Faculty`, but they're not. You simply need to specify the title-parameter of the `Employee`-c'tor somehow. I altered my post accordingly...

Comment: Also have a look at this link: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/114-constructors-and-initialization-of-derived-classes/

Comment: Thank you but i have a question. when i create a faculty object, objects title is going to be "mytitle" right ?

Comment: Look at how you're *calling* the Employee constructor.  Where is title declared?  Where does it come from?  That is what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: @TheNoobEternal: Yes. I cannot tell how you want construct the title, so I simply inserted some string in order to make it compile.

Answer (score 2):

Your Faculty constructor needs to explicitly construct Employee since it has no default constructor:

```
Faculty::Faculty(char* name, char* surname, char* sex, char* pob, Date* dob, Date* start, int level, int salary, Date* dolat, bool fulltime /*= true*/)
  : Employee(name, surname, ....) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The subject of initialization is an important aspect of constructing objects in C++. When you construct a class, there has to be an unambiguous way of initializing all the base classes of the class as well as all the member data of the class.

If any of the base classes or member data cannot be initialized without using explicit initializers, the compiler will report an error unless you add code to initialize them in the initializer list.

Make sure you use  the `Employee` constructor with the right arguments in the initializer list of `Faculty` constructor.

Change

```
Faculty::Faculty(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob,
                 Date* dob,Date* start,int level,int salary,
                 Date* dolat,bool fulltime/*= true*/)
{
}
```

to

```
Faculty::Faculty(char* name,char* surname,char* sex,char* pob,
                 Date* dob,Date* start,int level,int salary,
                 Date* dolat,bool fulltime/*= true*/) :
   Employe(name, surname, sex, pob, dob, start, level, salary, dolat, fulltime)
{
}
```